# Is there a place to see who all invested in a start-up before I invest?

Tags: investing, start-up

I want to invest in a start-up but first want to know if it's possible to locate all the current investor? I want to know every detail about this company from how they work internally to how they raised there money. This has proven difficult isn't there something i can find where the investor had to put there names and how much they invest?

Comment: The only way to get his info is to ask the startup.  If they want your money, they might be willing to share.

Comment: @gaefan Why not make this as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the best one for me is "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/microsoft" then go to the "Financials" tab, and there you have A) funding rounds b) IPO & Stock Price C)Investors, D) Investments , etc

Answer (score -3):

Yes. I am guessing this is in the U.S? In U.S if you called the company and asked for this information they legally have to tell you who there investors are. Even give you there contact information if you ask. Not that hard really.

Comment: Not true at all. What's the source/citation? A private company is not legally required to disclose anything, that's why it's private.